# Using threads on a list of items

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of items that I want to process with threads, each one takes about 10 minutes and I would like to do a couple at a time.

Right now I am doing them one at a time and it is taking a while.

```
old = ["old_item1","old_item2","old_item3","old_item4","old_item5"]
new = ["new_item1","new_item2","new_item3","new_item4","new_item5"]
area = ["area_item1","area_item2","area_item3","area_item4","area_item5"]

def func(x,y,z):
    print (x,y,z)

d = zip(old,new, area)

for e,f, g in d: 
  thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(e,f,g))
  thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(e,f,g))
  thread1.start()
  thread2.start()
  thread1.join()
  thread2.join()
```

So what I am trying to do is process

item1 with thread1 
item2 with thread2

item3 with thread1 
item4 with thread2

and finally
item5 with thread1

Comment: Is there a special reason for that association, or do you just want to multi-process the task?

Comment: like i said, each item takes around 10 minutes to process. its low cpu and low memory, it just takes a while. so rather than 50 minutes, i would like to split the time in half. i know i can make multiple lists and maybe multiple duplicate functions, i was thinking there may be a more elegant way to accomplish

Comment: Are you launching 2 times the same task in 2 threads?? In same iteration you start 2 threads with same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)'s [pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) which will take care of all the messy work for you. Using the [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) function you can run a function on all items of an iterable as its argument.

Something like:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

old = ["old_item1","old_item2","old_item3","old_item4","old_item5"]
new = ["new_item1","new_item2","new_item3","new_item4","new_item5"]
area = ["area_item1","area_item2","area_item3","area_item4","area_item5"]

def func(x,y,z):
    print (x,y,z)

d = zip(old,new, area)

with Pool() as pool:
    res = pool.starmap(func, d)
```

- Saving the result is not actually necessary here but in general the return value will be a list of all results corresponding with the given iterable.